# Filter based on string position?

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, filtering

I have a question about filtering string objects in a dataframe. Many of the stimuli I'm working with have a hash in them, but I only want to analyze the ones that have a hash at the beginning of the word (like [# T R] but not [T R #]). I've been able to filter my dataframe so that I only have stimuli that contain # using the following code:

```
initial_judgments = model_df_2[model_df_2[0].str.contains('#')]
```

However, I'm still wondering if there is a way to indicate that I only want stimuli with hash in the initial position of each stimuli. Is there a way to do this?

So far, my dataframe looks something like this:

```
    bigrams     judgments
1   AH1 N #     good
2   AE1 T #     good
3   EH1 T #     good
5   EY1 L #     good
6   AH1 NG #    good
...     ...     ...
84  # SH N  bad
85  # F T   bad
86  # Z R   bad
87  # N R   bad
88  # ZH V  bad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'bigrams':['# SH','SH #','# AB','AB']})
df.loc[df['bigrams'].str.startswith('#')]
```

Output

```
    bigrams
0   # SH
2   # AB
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!